# Question: Installing AMD driver error (Tools missing)

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon

I wanted to use AMD's driver for my computer on their website since I didn't like Ubuntu's recommended driver.

My graphics card is a Radeon HD 5700 and I used [this link](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English) and picked the latest beta, downloaded it, unzipped to my desktop changed the properties to run as a program, ran through the terminal and everything was going fine until [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5qQst7RKhvqXzdJaEY0V1FkX0E/edit?usp=sharing) happened.

It says that I am missing tools for installation but when I look at installation requirements on the AMD website for this driver it seems like I have them all.

Please someone help me.

[Image 2](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5qQst7RKhvqXzdJaEY0V1FkX0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you do not find the answer to your question at the link @StephenMyall commented, please post your /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5qQst7RKhvqSGJGMlJYSDQwNFk/edit?usp=sharing

I am missing some headers it seems. I don't know how it happened; seems I need to find the tool and add to my system. Thanks for the help.